# Comparing observed and expected diets of two different species

Tags: regression, group-differences, paired-data, difference-in-difference, compositional-data

My data consists of dietary data from two species (C1 and C2) and expected diets for each species (E1, E2) generated from a combination of variables, but is based on their foraging behavior. What I want to test is whether differences in foraging behavior between the two species lead to differences in their diets. There are 29 prey item categories.

```
Prey Item,C1,C2,E1,E2
Item 1,0.001396648,0,0.006173874,0.00093689
Item 2,0.019553073,0.019762846,0.074044293,0.026270734
Item 3,0.148044693,0.043478261,0.029199289,0.029657448
Item 4,0.009776536,0.023715415,0.021286946,0.023841657
Item 5,0.13547486,0.154150198,0.134092322,0.143487931
Item 6,0.015363128,0.027667984,0.005382245,0.003968741
Item 7,0.069832402,0.003952569,0.217147284,0.183648673
Item 8,0.17877095,0.276679842,0.172995833,0.148715577
Item 9,0.022346369,0.007905138,0.016949998,0.029785743
Item 10,0,0,0.002769979,0.000621657
Item 11,0.008379888,0.086956522,0.013446871,0.007693514
Item 12,0.020949721,0,0.00928104,0.008616542
Item 13,0.009776536,0,0.003133804,0.004925754
Item 14,0.001396648,0.003952569,0.002518525,0.00031456
Item 15,0.009776536,0.023715415,0.001549977,0.000285538
Item 16,0,0,0.000685986,0.000104099
Item 17,0,0,0.000685986,0.000104099
Item 18,0,0.003952569,0.001371972,0.000208198
Item 19,0.233240223,0.003952569,0.042483895,0.031923148
Item 20,0,0.003952569,0.001727983,0.000362878
Item 21,0,0,0.002258419,0.001187943
Item 22,0.002793296,0.035573123,0.000685986,0.000104099
Item 23,0.087988827,0.276679842,0.213165131,0.330990013
Item 24,0.002793296,0,0.02066917,0.013710854
Item 25,0.005586592,0,0.004338279,0.006239274
Item 26,0.015363128,0,0.000408076,0.000876974
Item 27,0,0,0.001546836,0.001417467
Item 28,0.001396648,0,0,0
Item 29,0,0.003952569,0,0
```

My initial approach was to take the difference in percent composition in the diet of species 1 and 2 for each prey item (C1-C2), as well as the difference in expected diet of species 1 and 2 for each prey item (E1-E2), and run a linear regression. The residuals of the model had really fat tails centered at 0, and some very high leverage points. I cube rooted the differences in observed diet, which fixed the problem with the fat tails, but not the leverage. I am hesitant to try robust regression and down weight the high leverage points because these are generally the prey items that were consumed the most, and if anything should probably be more important than the food items that neither species consumed in high amounts.

Is a regression analysis even appropriate? I'm not really sure that regression is best to test for this. Does anyone have suggestions on how to analyze this data? I prefer to work in R when possible.

Comment: Realized there is an issue with my original regression method above as the differences in the relative abundance of consumed prey taxa (C1-C2) would sum to 0, making them not independent. I do have the raw abundance values for the actual dietary data to remedy this problem.